# Associate a record to all ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a models `Benefit` and `Designation`.

In my `seeds.rb` file, I want to do something like:

```
benefits = ['Health Insurance', 'Provident Fund']
benefits.each do |benefits|
  Benefit.create(name: benefits, designation_id: Designation.all.ids)
end
```

So that the benefits 'Health Insurance' and 'Provident Fund' are added for all the `Designations` that are already present.
But the **Designation.all.ids** doesnt work, how to do this?

Schema for `benefits`:

```
  create_table "benefits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "designation_id"
    t.index ["designation_id"], name: "index_benefits_on_designation_id"
  end
```

Comment: You can not store multiple values in a single bigint type column.

Answer (score 2):

If I well understand what you want is:

- A designation can have many benefits
- A benefit can have many designations

You can't achieve that with your current db schema.

You need to introduce an **intermediate model**, something like this:

```
create_table :benefits do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :designations do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :designation_benefits do |t|
  t.belongs_to :benefit, index: true
  t.belongs_to :designation, index: true
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Then,

```
class Benefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :designation_benefits
  has_many :designations, through: :designation_benefits
end

class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :designation_benefits
  has_many :benefits, through: :designation_benefits
end

class DesignationBenefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :benefit
  belong_to :designation
end
```

And finaly you can create records like this:

```
['Health Insurance', 'Provident Fund'].each do |name|
  benefit = Benefit.create!(name: name)
  benefit.designations << Designation.all
end

Designation.first.benefits.count # => 2
```

See example and documentation here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Actually my schema is pretty complex I just added the bit I thought was relevant. I have has_and_belongs_to_many between `Employee` and `Benefits`. Furthermore, `Designation` has many `Employees`.

Comment: It's actualy a bad practice if I were you I'd change it https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: @abdulwasey20 it doesn't seem that the relations between `employees` and `benefits` or `designations` and `employees` is related to your problem, does it ? What's the relation between `benefits` and `designations` ? Can you show your models ?

Comment: Benefit `belongs_to :designation` and Deisgnation `has_many :benefits`

Comment: So you can only have 1 `designation_id` stored in a row of the table `benefits`. And my answer is relevant 

Comment: Or you could change the relation between `designations` and `benefits` for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` but as I said it's a bad practice, see this article: https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/#

Comment: have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

With current structure of benefits table you can't.

What you can do,

**Solution 1:**

Change `designation_id` column datatype as `string` or `text`.

Then save value as,

```
  Benefit.create(name: benefits, designation_id: Designation.all.ids.join(','))
```

**Solution 2:**

Create better association between your `Benefit` and `Designation` model.

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me like I wanted it to:

```
benefits = ['Health Insurance', 'Provident Fund']
designation_ids = Designation.all.pluck(:id)
benefits.each do |benefits|
    designation_ids.each do |designation|
        Benefit.create(name: benefits, designation_id: designation)
    end
end
```

`designation_ids` contains a list of all the ids and the nested loop adds both the `benefits` to all the ids in the list.

Comment: Well that's not DRY at all, you're creating multiple records of `benefits` with the same name. One day you'll be stuck without any escape. Imagine you need to get all `designations` records that has the `'Health Insurance'` benefit. With my answer you could just do `Benefit.find_by(name: 'Health Insurance').designations`, with yours you'd need to do something like `Benefit.where(name: 'Health Insurance').map { |benefit| benefit.designations }.flatten` which is very efficient.

Comment: **not efficient**